# Can't Bind the Value in Select2 Selectbox

Tags: visualforce, angularjs

Can anyone tell me how to bind the value to select2 select box in visualforce page?

The below code does not bind the existing account name value to the field in the edit form. This form gets activated after clicking the edit button.

```
<apex:page controller="ContactUpdateController" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<html class="fixed">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.js" />

  <script>
    $(function(){
      // turn the element to select2 select style
        $("#ss").select2({  });
    });
  </script>

        <!-- AngularJs-->
        <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.css,'/css/bootstrap-theme.css')}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.js,'/js/angular.js')}"></script>

        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', []);

            function getContact(id) {
                angular.element(document.getElementById('body')).scope().myfunction(id);
            }
            function updateContact(id){
                angular.element(document.getElementById('body')).scope().update(id);
            }

            //defining module
            var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

            // create angular controller
            myapp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {

                 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                            '{!$RemoteAction.ContactUpdateController.getAccount}',

                            function(result, event){
                                if (event.status) {
                                    $scope.AccountList =result;

                                    alert($scope.AccountList[0].Name);

                                } else if (event.type === 'exception') 
                                    alert(event.message);
                            $scope.$apply();
                            }, 
                            {escape: true}
                        );

                 $scope.myfunction = function (id) {

                    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                            '{!$RemoteAction.ContactUpdateController.getContact}',
                            id,
                            function(result, event){
                                if (event.status) {
                                    document.getElementById('lastname').innerHTML =result.LastName;
                                    document.getElementById('accountname').innerHTML =result.Account.Name;

                                    $scope.lastname = result.LastName;
                                    $scope.accid = result.Account.Id;
                                    $scope.accountname = result.Account.Name;   
                                } else if (event.type === 'exception') 
                                    alert(event.message);
                            }, 
                            {escape: true}
                        );
                    };

                $scope.updateContact =function(id){
                    // Set the 'submitted' flag to true
                    $scope.submitted = true;

                    if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {

                        if($scope.lastname==null)
                            $scope.lastname="";

                        if($scope.accid==null)
                            $scope.accid="";

                      <!-- Java script Remoting-->
                        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                            '{!$RemoteAction.ContactUpdateController.updateContact}',
                           id,$scope.firstname,$scope.lastname,$scope.phoneno,$scope.accid,
                            function(result, event){
                                if (event.status) {
                                    var id =result.Id;
                                    $scope.myfunction(id);
                                    $scope.showme1 =false;
                                } else if (event.type === 'exception') 
                                    alert(event.message);
                            }, 
                            {escape: true}
                        );
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Please fill the required fields!");
                    }
                };
            });

        </script>
    </head>
<body id="body" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mainController" onload="getContact('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}')">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

            <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
            <!-- FORM : YOU CAN DISABLE, HTML5 VALIDATION BY USING "novalidate" ATTRIBUTE-->
            <form name="userForm"  novalidate="novalidate" ng-show="showme1">
                <!-- LastName -->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && (userForm.name.$dirty || submitted)}">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" ng-required="true" />
                    <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && (userForm.name.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Last name is required.</p>
                </div>

                <!-- LookUpField-->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.contactno.$invalid  && (userForm.contactno.$dirty ) }">
                    <label >Account Name</label>
                    <select id="ss"  class="form-control" ng-model="accid"  >
                        <option ng-repeat="item in AccountList" ng-selected="{{item.Name}}"   value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>  

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateContact('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}')">Submit</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showme1=false">Back</button>
            </form>
            <form name="userForm1"  novalidate="novalidate" ng-hide="showme1">

                 <!-- LastName -->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && (userForm.name.$dirty || submitted)}">
                    <label>Last Name</label> : <label id="lastname"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.contactno.$invalid  && (userForm.contactno.$dirty ) }">
                    <label>Account Name</label> : <label id="accountname"></label>
                </div>

                <!-- ng-disabled FOR ENABLING AND DISABLING SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Register</button>-->
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showme1=true" value="Edit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

My Controller

```
global with sharing class ContactUpdateController {

    @RemoteAction
    global static List<Account> getAccount() {
        List<Account> accList=[select id,Name from Account];
        return accList;
     }

    @RemoteAction
    global static Contact getContact(string cId) {
        String ContactId=cId.trim();

        contact c= [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName,Phone,Account.Id,Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Id= :ContactId];
        return c;
    }

    @RemoteAction
    global static Contact updateContact(string cId,string lastname,string accid){        
        String ContactId=cId.trim();
        Contact c=new Contact(id=ContactId);

        if(accid!=null)
            c.accountid=accid.trim();

        c.LastName=lastname.trim();

        update c;
        return c;
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong in this code, any ideas?

Modified lookup field code:

```
<!-- LookUpField-->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.contactno.$invalid  && (userForm.contactno.$dirty ) }">
   <label >Account Name</label>
   <select id="ss"  class="form-control" ng-model="accid" 
             ng-selected="{{acc.Id == accid}}" ng-options="acc.Id as acc.Name for acc in AccountList">
   </select>


                               </div>
```

The problem is that the actual account for this Contact is not populated when I go to edit. It is blank: 
 [image]

I want the field value to be populated with the current value so that it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You might consider trimming down the code you want to troubleshoot instead of the whole page.

Comment: you say that it isn't binding to account name. just a quick browse shows you have an ng-model reference to lastname and accid, but I don't see any inputs bound to account name. Are you sure you included it?

Comment: @Peter : I have included $scope.accid = result.Account.Id;

Comment: so that it will bind the account name

Comment: @Peter : one more issue is: I have to double click the submit button while updating record

Comment: @Peter Please Response.

Comment: Double-click is probably a new question.

Comment: This is a huge page. Can you please excerpt and remove the code that is irrelevant to help people understand exactly where things have gone wrong? Especially things like removing irrelevant markup and CSS will be most helpful. It also sounds like you have a couple of questions...one about the binding of the select box, and another around binding to AccountName. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter : I have edit my code (obviated some unnecessary js and css files).

Comment: @Peter: Now can you tell me what is the problem and why it doesnt bind the value to lookup...

Comment: @LaceySnr : Please help me why the account name is not binding in select box?

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but it looks like you're using ng-selected wrong. You appear to be setting it for *every* option in your select list when you should only be setting it for the default value. What behavior are you seeing. You state account name, "is not binding". But what behavior is leading you to that conclusion. Can you show a screenshot of what is happening? Also, what is the console telling you. You might want to use Batarang to help get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Peter: I have added the some modification and snapshot of the page as you mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you are using `ng-selected`.

What you did was this:

```
                <label >Account Name</label>
                <select id="ss"  class="form-control" ng-model="accid"  >
                    <option ng-repeat="item in AccountList" ng-selected="{{item.Name}}"   value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</option>
                </select>
```

What you need is in fact this:

```
                <label >Account Name</label>
                <select id="ss"  class="form-control" ng-model="accid"  >
                    <option ng-repeat="item in AccountList" ng-selected="{{item.Name===accountname}}"   value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</option>
                </select>
```

The documentation for ngSelected states that if the expression is "truthy" then set the selected attribute for this in HTML.

Your code had the equivalent of making *every* item in the list truthy, in effect making every item selected, and HTML being HTML, it probably threw up its hands and said, "whatever..." and didn't show any of them.

By testing each current item name against the actual Contact's account, you can make *only the current account name* the true item, and the rest won't be set.

Looking at the html page source, with the correct expression, we get all select options set to be false, except the one true one: 
[image]

I don't have an explanation for why your alternative code didn't work, or why the simple binding of `accid` isn't working. It looks like it should, but again, you'd need to look at the browser developer tools to understand it better.

In reality, the code works for me in all three instances (just binding `accid`, with the boolean expression for `ng-selected`, and with the `item.Name` expression). But I don't have access to your static resources. I'm just accessing AngularJS off of their CDN at this url:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Perhaps you're using an older version of AngularJS and you are experiencing a bug there?

Comment: Can you give me the cdn link new version of angularjs

Comment: Can you share your mail id so that I Can Send my static resource files

Comment: I assume you've tried clearing your browser's cache, trying different browsers, yeah?

Comment: am trying different browser but still it gives same

Comment: By the way, the CDN link is up. I made a typo in the markdown.